# MVC action called twice (only in chrome)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm wondering why a simple test action is called twice when browsed in chrome.

I am aware of the issue when its caused by img tags etc. But I have reproduced the issue using a simple (empty markup) action which only returns an H1 tag and nothing else.

Firefox and IE tested OK with this. Anyone got this issue before?

Here is the action method which gets called twice:

```
    public ContentResult Test()
    {
        return Content("<h1>Test page<h1/>", "text/html");
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751266/asp-net-mvc-action-is-called-twice ?

Comment: Gone through all the different reasons in this questions ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2009092/1236044

Comment: Yes, nothing related to img tags etc.. I dont have any sophisticated html..

Comment: You can install fiddler and check to see the requests that are getting made by the chrome process and confirm if that indeed is the case.

Comment: I'm getting this same behavior in Chrome. It was fine until 30 minutes ago, then started calling an action method twice.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code in my mvc application.It is working perfectly.My chrome version is  **45.0.2454.7 dev-m** .Please download latest version of chrome i think it should be work for you