# A file manage system - using asp.net mvc and wcf

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I'm trying develop a File Manage System for user upload/download file.

This system include two part(machine):

1. Web Server(asp.net mvc) : File CRUD
2. File Server (WCF) : using Windows File System or Nosql store file.

When use download a file, the process is...https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmL5K.png

The file has been send twice!

I hope File Server directly send file back to browser, but have no idea how to do it.

My wcf service contract is like:

```
interface FileService {
  Stream Download(string filename);
  void Upload(string filename, Stream file);
}
```

ASP.net mvc code:

```
class FileController : Controller {
  HttpResponseMessage Get(string filename) {
    // call wcf service here, and return.
  }
}
```

Please suggest, Thanks!

---

Update:

Not `action` call twice...

I mean the file send twice: from file server to web server to browser

Maybe it my program's architeture problem, wcf service shouldn't return a stream?

Comment: It's not WCF issue or anything between WCF and ASP.NET. I think it is related with executig `Action` twice in a controller.

Comment: I am sorry i didn't say it clearly, I had update my post...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:[asp-net-mvc-action-is-called-twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751266/asp-net-mvc-action-is-called-twice). They suggest to add a script for returning false when a link is clicked (don't mention the MVC2 version).
If that doesn't help take a look at this [page-loads-twice-in-google-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009092/page-loads-twice-in-google-chrome). If you have an img tag with an empty src element in your html that might cause the double call.