# IActionResult call multiple times while click on link in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I click on the anchor tag and set a breakpoint on the Controller action below, the breakpoint hit 2 times consecutively why is this 2nd call trigger?

**Here is my anchor tag code:**

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Trip" asp-action="Add" asp-route-id="Page1" style="text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold;">Add Trip</a>
```

**Controller code:**

```
public IActionResult Add(string id = "Page1")
{
   return View(id);
}
```

**View code:**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add Trip - Page 1";
}


<h1>Page 1</h1>
```

Comment: Do you click or double-click?

Comment: No, i don't do that

Comment: What is the value of `Request.Method` during the first and second call?

Comment: i am getting "GET" in Request.Method value in both calls

Comment: Both times? Then please post the complete View. This is not the actual view code you use. You have some html, css or javascript in your view which causes the second request. See [mcve]

Comment: @NineBerry no it's a complete view beside this view code shared layout loaded with it. ok, let me try solutions from the link.

Comment: @NineBerry thanks for the link. AdBlocker was causing this issue.

Comment: If your Add action modifies data, you should only allow it via the "POST" and not the "GET" method. This is good practice in web development. Using GET for modifying data is dangerous because you cannot prevent actions that perform that request even without user interaction. (An attacker using the url in some way, a browser doing pre-caching and so on...)

Answer (score 0):

This link solved my problem. AdBlocker was the reason of same call hit twice.
[ASP.NET MVC Action is Called Twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751266/asp-net-mvc-action-is-called-twice)